# automatic high DPI adaptation of running winforms app

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have several applications written with winforms using .net 6 and visual basic, all start very sharp even with high dpi display, but if the applications are started and I try to change the dpi settings they are seen blurry, to solve I have to restart the applications .
How can I handle this without restarting applications? Maybe with some DPI change event?

Comment: An app that supports per/monitor dpi changes also automatically supports this setup change.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Add to the Project's file `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>`. This affects the Dpi Awareness mode set by the auto-generated code that `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()` calls.

Comment: I use .net 6 and I don't know which file to put it in

Comment: The starting Project's configuration file (`.csproj`). In VS 2022, in Solution Explorer you can right-click the starting Project and select `Edit Project File` from the Menu

Comment: done but I didn't solve it, I put `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>` in the `<PropertyGroup>`tag